# Not-related question showed

Tags: bug

Not-related with java question showed in java-filtered question list.

[image]

Comment: I am sure it was a caching issue. The java tag was [removed from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17271098/revisions) round about the same time when you search for [java] questions.

Comment: Just refresh the page it will not show you now.

Comment: I tried few times, but it was there. Now it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It had the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag at 8:33AM, based on [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17271098/revisions). I guess that you accessed the web just when the tag was removed and that filter was still showing this question.

Comment: The question was still in list when I refreshed the page.

Comment: Mmmm then it must be a mini-bug or some caching problem.

Comment: Right. That's why I posted it on meta.stackoverflow ;)